# replace the value of selected value from select list in url

Tags: html, jquery

i am running in to any isssue , i have one select list ,when the user selected the option from the select list i want that value to be append to the url but when i user againa selected another option i want that value to be replaced with new value in url .

here is my code

```
   <select id="drop"  >
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>


js : 

   

     $('#drop').on('change', function (e) {
            if (e.handled !== true) {
              e.handled = true;
              var url = https://www.geoplug.docksal/sales/rentals?year=2019;
              window.location.href = url+'?sort='+this.value;
            }
          });
```

here i am adding new parameter name sort with the selected value , when the user selects another one i want to replace it with new value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pushState to change the URL of your app. And use localStorage to initially save your base url.

```js
let url = location.href;
localStorage.setItem("url", url);
$('#drop').on('change', function(e) {
  if (e.handled !== true) {
    e.handled = true;

    if (typeof(history.pushState) != "undefined") {
      //get the url
      let newURL = localStorage.getItem("url") + '?sort=' + this.value;
      let title = this.value;
      let obj = {
        Title: title,
        Url: newURL
      };

      console.log("url ", newURL);
      history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<select id="drop">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hii this solution works fine but i need to reload the page when eve i addess the new value to url for that i am using window.location.replace(newUrl); , when i uses this one it wil not replacing the old value just smiply adds another variable to url  , can you help me with this

Comment: The page is reloaded. Thats why the back button is activated when you change the dropdown

Comment: Ohh got you , so now how to solve this issue in case of reload ?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: i am sorry for not explaining correctly , i am using the  window.location.replace(newURL); to reload the page after history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url); , in this case it not replacing the value it is simply adding the new parameter with selected value

Comment: Why did you add `window.location.replace(newURL);`? `history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);` is already replacing the url and creating a new page, is it not?

Comment: not really , it is adding the url parameter but it is not refreshing the page,thats why i added window.location.replace

Comment: What does your localhost say?

Comment: it got the url parameter correct , it is just no reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

You are having some syntax errors. Strings must be encapsulated by `'` or `"`.
You should use `&` instead of another `?` if there are already existing url parameters.

```
https://example.com/?foo=bar&baz=beep&boop=hotdog
```

Also make sure that the `onchange` listner is under the `document ready`.

Since you are using jquery, you can get the value on change by using `$(this).val()`

```
<select id="drop">
    <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

```
$(function(){
    $('#drop').on('change', function (e) {
        var url = 'https://www.geoplug.docksal/sales/rentals?year=2019';
        window.location.href = url+'&sort='+$(this).val();
    });
})
```